# Convert PDFs to Images using pdf2image in python

Tags: python

I have a folder contains files of type PDF, PNG, and JPEG. I'm trying to convert PDF files to images and this is the code I've tried:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path, convert_from_bytes


from pdf2image.exceptions import (
 PDFInfoNotInstalledError,
 PDFPageCountError,
 PDFSyntaxError
)

images = convert_from_path('41117 UIs in eng.pdf')

for i, image in enumerate(images):
    fname = 'image'+str(i)+'.jpg'
    image.save(fname, "JPEG")
```

Clearly this code is only for a single pdf file and I want to transfer the code to serve several pdf files that are mixed with other file types in the same folder.

please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this (this script finds pdf files in the same directory with your python program):

```
 import os


from pdf2image import convert_from_path, convert_from_bytes

from pdf2image.exceptions import (
    PDFInfoNotInstalledError,
    PDFPageCountError,
    PDFSyntaxError
)

# get all pdf files from directory
pdf_files = [filename for filename in os.listdir(
    '.') if filename.endswith('.pdf')]

for pdf_file in pdf_files:
    images = convert_from_path(pdf_file)

    print(pdf_file)

    for i, image in enumerate(images):
        fname = pdf_file+'_image'+str(i)+'.jpg'
        image.save(fname, "JPEG")
```

Comment: Actually, when I tried the code only one pdf file has been converted to an image where there are 3 more pdfs. What is the problem?

Comment: Is the script in the same directory with your pdfs?

Comment: I've got this error when I tried the updated code: `I/O Error: Couldn't open file '/Users/inour/Desktop/convert2image\a.pdf': No such file or directory.`

Comment: Yes my machine runs windows so the path for you is wrong, i updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for being patient with me, actually last version of your code runs successfully but after changing the `pdf_files` to the old value. like this: `pdf_files = [filename for filename in os.listdir('.') if filename.endswith('.pdf')]`